# Getting kicked out of Openshift server after a while

Tags: ssh, openshift

I'm using ssh to connect to an openshift server. Every once in a while, like every 15 minutes, i get kicked out (disconnected). How can I prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you ssh into your gear, run the `unset TMOUT` command and that should remove the timeout and should help keep you from getting disconnected.

Comment: Thanks Corey.  I worked but my connection was closed in less time. Perhaps to erase that another variable variable takes less default value. I solve it by setting a large value after unset line.

Answer (score 1):

Another option aside from removing the timeout all together is to increase it, for example:

```
unset TMOUT
export TMOUT=2880000
```

Comment: you should flag questions as duplicates rather than writing the same answer multiple times.

Comment: Oks Robert. When I press "flag" I dont see "duplicate option". Thanks

Comment: Choose the should be closed... option and you'll get the option to select a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is for the sessions and you will have to change it every time you connect. If you want to make it permanent try to edit `sshd_config` or `ssh_config` (whichever is used to configure timeout) file. In my case, it was located in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Below configuration worked for me:

```
ClientAliveInterval 6000
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

**NOTE:

Keep In Mind That If It Is Controlled By Your Administrator Team, None Of These Will Work! They can control it in network VPN, AD (active directory) or another security layer. If so, you are not alone :)**

Answer (score 0):

If `TMOUT` is read only, then you cannot change the setting of `TMOUT`.
`ssh_config` change would not work either.

You can try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222283/read-only-tmout-variable-workaround-to-disable-automatically-exit-shell-when-t/258477#258477